# Build datetime column in R

Tags: r, datetime

I have 2 columns

one is date :

```
2011-04-13
2013-07-29
2010-11-23
```

the other is time :

```
3
22
15
```

I want to make a new column contains date time

it will be like this

```
2011-04-13 3:00:00
2013-07-29 22:00:00
2010-11-23 15:00:00
```

I managed to combine them as string
but when i convert them to datetime i get only date the time disappears

any idea how to get date and time in one column?

my script

```
data <- read.csv("d:\\__r\\hour.csv")
data$date <- as.POSIXct(paste(data$dteday , paste(data$hr, ":00:00", sep=""), sep=" "))
```

Comment: There are various other ways to do this as well but this actually works for me. `as.POSIXct(paste(data$dteday , paste(data$hr, ":00:00", sep=""), sep=" "))`

Comment: if i convert this to datetime it dont get the right results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found this fixed the problem

```
data$date <- as.POSIXct(strptime(paste(data$dteday , paste(data$hr, ":00:00", sep=""), sep=" "), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

Answer (score 4):

as example you can use `ymd_hm` function from `lubridate`:

```
a <- c("2014-09-08", "2014-09-08", "2014-09-08")
b <- c(3, 4, 5)

library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
tibble(a, b) %>% 
  mutate(time = paste0(a, " ", b, "-0"),
         time = ymd_hm(time))
```

output would be:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  a              b time               
  <chr>      <dbl> <dttm>             
1 2014-09-08     3 2014-09-08 03:00:00
2 2014-09-08     4 2014-09-08 04:00:00
3 2014-09-08     5 2014-09-08 05:00:00
```